# Difficulty applying stylesheets

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Afternoon.

I am attempting to format some tables but I am finding that none of my styles are being applied to this page.

I've attempted deleting the php in case it was causing something to go amiss and I've tried using in-line styles but that doesn't seem to want to be applied either.

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['message'] = '';
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "User", "password", "DarrenOBrien");

   if ($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
      $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products") or die($mysqli->error);
   }
   else {
      header('location: register.php');
   }
?>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--Navbar-->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="welcome.php">PHP Project </a>
       </div>
       <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li><a href="welcome.php">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
           <li class="active"><a href="products.php">Products</a></li>
         </ul>
         <a href="logout.php" class="navbar-brand pull-right">Logout</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
   <!--End of Navbar-->

   <div class="container-fluid" id="products">
     <?php
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
       echo "<table> <tr><td>" . $row['productName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['productDescription'] . "</td></tr>" . "<img style='height: 30px;' src='".$row['productImage']."'>" . "</td></tr>" . "</table>"; //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
       }
     ?>
   </div>
<!-- Required bootstrap scripts -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- End of required bootstrap scripts -->
</body>
```

Comment: What's in styles.css? Also, is the console showing any errors?

Comment: Css and js linked properly ? ... Are you sure ?

Comment: Some simple styling. Things like max-width of elements and background color. Console is not showing errors.

Comment: My paths are fine. I've also attempted to use in-line styles which also aren't working.

Comment: Can you give an example of an inline style that isn't working? That really doesn't make much sense, and seems to point to something more like a caching issue.

Comment: It did seem to be some kind of caching issue. It spontaneously fixed itself a minute or two ago. One of the stranger things I've come across.

Comment: Show the generated HTML only. Noone cares about your php.

Answer (score 1):

> I am attempting to format some tables.

Your using bootstrap, so you need to add the table class to your table.

`echo "<table class=\"table\"> <tr><td>...`

> but I am finding that none of my styles are being applied to this
>   page.

Check your relative paths to the assets, if this is file is accessed from sub directory's you will need to add a slash, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Also your missing the  root. e.g:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

Comment: My paths are fine. I've also attempted to use in-line styles which also aren't working.